# how can i make click enabled at owl-carousel slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

[image]

I customize jQuery owl-carousel and make this slider.Now i want to add another options. The option is when I clicked any images then it have to go center.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO .. please include your relevant code on the question, enough to reproduce your issue, include what you have tried.

Comment: $('.owl-item').on('click', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass('cloned')){
      $this.removeClass('cloned');
      $this.addClass('active center');
      
     
    }
     });

Comment: I try this but the problem is  center image also being in center

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hasanm025/kpaw5bna/